# C# MVC load ActionResult with javascript with parameter

Tags: javascript, actionresult

I want to load an action result with javascript. I found some solution on stackoverflow, but they aint working.

I have this piece of code that when its friday it should load this view. It looks like this:

```
 var from = jQuery('#orderForDate').datepicker().val().split("-");
        var f = new Date(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0]);
        var n = f.getDay();

        orderForDate = jQuery('#orderForDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" }).val();

        if (n == 5) {
            console.log('friday baby!');
            var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Bestellen", "Cart", new { orderForDate=orderForDate}))';
            window.location = url;
        }
```

This is the controller is should load:

```
 public ActionResult Bestellen(string orderForDate)
    {
        ViewBag.date = string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderForDate) ? DateTime.Now.Date : DateTime.ParseExact(orderForDate, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL"));
        User user = _db.Users.Find(_db.GetCurrentUserId());

        var vm = new BestellenViewModel { ShowFavoritesAsDefault = user.ShowFavoritesAsDefault };
        return PartialView(vm);
    }
```

The problem is, when I click on a date that is friday in my datepicker, the browsers loads this url/page

`http://localhost:54408/Cart/@Html.Raw(Url.Action(%22Bestellen%22,%20%22Cart%22,%20new%20%7B%20orderForDate=orderForDate%7D))`

And I obviously don't get the desired page.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your url link. `http://localhost:54408/Cart/@Html.Raw(Url.Action(%22Bestellen%22,%20%22Cart%22,%20new%20%7B%20orderForDate=orderForDate%7D))`. It is not what you want. Try: `window.location = '/Cart/Bestellen?orderForDate=' + orderForDate`

Comment: Thanks that fixed it! Why is my not working? Can you explain that?

Comment: As I said look on your url link. You try to connect razor and js and write to url string which is `@Html.Raw(Url.Action(%22Bestellen%22,%20%22Cart%22,%20new%20%7B%20orderForDate=orderForDate%7D))` and it is not real path to your Controller and Action.